# To blog or not to blog?

Tags: discussion, blogoverflow

I'm sorry, but our blog is something we hardly ever talk about around here.

> http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/

Have you ever seen this post? Isn't it helpful?

Well, there's this little issue. The resources for BlogOverflow are going to be decommissioned (to some degree) so we have a few options:

- we can either keep the site branding as-is, but make everything static, so nothing ever goes away, and it never changes either,
- or we can setup a new site somewhere else and they can give us a dump of the data and we can stand it up over yonder.

---

#### So let's talk about the brass tax.

It's a really shiny idea, sure, but as with all taxes, we have to pay the piper at some point. And the thing is, the most prolific of the posters here had blogs before they became known here (or they were known here because of their blogs, ya know, whichever) so most of our more well-known authors don't really get a lot of air-play out of the blogoverflow platform.

---

## So, these are the options:

### 1) We re-start the blog concept for dba.se, we gather several writers, we all make commitments to add something at a reasonable time-scale (with 10 invested people writing one article a month we can do a post every 3 days, that's pretty active)

OR

### 2) We just say "it was a cute idea but .... I've got other fish to fry, sorry charlie". No harm, no foul.

---

Ok, vote below with upvotes. Downvotes don't count.  Most upvotes by October 31 carry the decision. I'll take the mantle of getting us onto a new site if that's what we decide, but that's only as a default so someone can own things. If someone else wants to own that I'll definitely let them.

Comment: Lovely eggcorn in "brass tax".

Comment: You're welcome Tim

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### I'm voting for

> We just say "it was a cute idea but .... I've got other fish to fry, sorry charlie". No harm, no foul.

Existing blog pages stay frozen where they are - *with the same URL*.

---

comments below if you have something constructive to add. Thanks.

Comment: If we do this, the concensus is that the SE team migrates things over to static pages. I'm not sure if this was 100% obvious.

Comment: I think we can do this while still keeping the other option available for us to switch to at any point.

Comment: I'm voting for this, BUT the excellent post by @Aaaron http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/ needs preserving somewhere on the main DBA.se site. I suggest as an answer to a new mod-crafted community question.

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ it's not going anywhere with this option, it'll stay as a static page for us.

Answer (score 4):

### I'm voting for

> We re-start the blog concept for dba.se, we gather several writers, we all make commitments to add something at a reasonable time-scale (with 10 invested people writing one article a month we can do a post every 3 days, that's pretty active)

---

comments below if you have something constructive to add. Thanks.

Comment: I think before we can reasonably vote for this option we need to have people commit to adding content. Without contributors this option is meaningless. Even if it carries it will die on the vine. I'd read the blog if it had regular interesting content, but I don't feel I'm enough of a guru to add meaningful content.

Comment: The funny thing is that people writing beginner level content is still needed, so long as it is well written and well referenced.

Comment: I'll commit to being one of the 10 if this passes.

Comment: I would be interested in writing but would like to know more before committing.

Comment: Sorry fellas, as with the last time we tried this not enough interest. Maybe we can do something off-site. If you're interested send me an email at cole@jcolebrand.info and I'll be happy to followup and we can see about starting something off-site.

Comment: @jcolebrand That's ok. At least we tried. I'll just start dedicating time to write on my own blog. I appreciate you offering though.

Comment: It'd be nice if http://stackoverflow.com/documentation could be adapted for these uses, but it seems like that system wouldn't really be blog-friendly.  In any case, I just created a semi-bloggy post @ http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/154185/52150 in the main DBA.se. If posts like this are helpful, I assume it'd accumulate upvotes and rise in the google ranking for targeted searches. meta.dba.se could have a single thread with links to the bloggy posts?  Or we could tag with "DBAblog" or some such thing